# Getting previous date from current date by using number of days in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have table given as below:

| patient_id | date_isd | gap_klm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 02/06/2023 | 517 |

I want to create a new column called `'First_date'` which is obtained by subtracting `'gap_klm'` from `'date_isd'`
i.e date_isd is 02/06/2023so if I subtract 517 days from it resultant date is 01/01/2022. I need output as given below.

| patient_id | date_isd | gap_klm | First_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 02/06/2023 | 517 | 01/01/2022 |

Please help I tried to found solutions but didn't got any.

Comment: Try this: `df['first'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_isd']) + pd.DateOffset(days=df.gap_klm.values[0])`